# Change frame of UITableView of UITableViewController inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the frame of my UITableView. I try todo it with this code:

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
self.tableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 490);
```

I do this in viewWillAppear. When I insert a log here, it shows me, that the tableView frame is changed.

But, when I end up in viewDidAppear the tableView is back to it's original size. I set the autoresizesSubviews to NO for the view of the NavigationController.

When I change the frame in viewDidAppear it works, but this looks a bit crapy, because the frame is resized after it is displayed on screen :(

What can I change to get this working?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a UIViewController with a UITableView instead of a UITableViewController.

With that I can resize the the frame of the tableView inside viewDidLoad and everything is fine:)